# Direct Connection Between Two Macs: Don't Share to Public Connection?

Tags: macos, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two OSX Computers in Physical Proximity: Options?](https://superuser.com/questions/198274/two-osx-computers-in-physical-proximity-options)

I am using VNC between two macs that are hooked up to the same wireless network AND are hooked up directly (via Firewire now, via Ethernet when I get a cable, no cross-over cable needed, apparently). Is there any way to insist that sharing does NOT happen over the Wifi connection?

I have checked the firewall options but to no avail. I've also checked under Network and Sharing. Can't find anything relevant.

Comment: I answered this on your other question: http://superuser.com/questions/198274/two-osx-computers-in-physical-proximity-options/198282#198282